# INSERT Using a SELECT Does Not Appear To Work for Top(n) Where 'n' > 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I am using MS SQL Server 2014.

For simplicity, suppose I have a linked server 'LinkSrvr' with database 'LinkDB', and table 'LinkTbl', as well as a local server 'LocalSrvr' with database 'LocalDB' and table 'LocalTbl'.

Assume both tables have identical structures (Id int identity(1,1), Val varchar(max) NULL), and IdentityInsert is ON for LocalTbl.

```
SELECT TOP(n) Id, Val FROM [LinkSrvr].[LinkDB].[dbo].[LinkTbl]
```

(where 'n' is any positive integer) returns records almost immediately.

In addition,

```
INSERT INTO [LocalDB].[dbo].[LocalTbl] (Id, Val) 
SELECT TOP(1) Id, Val 
FROM [LinkSrvr].[LinkDB].[dbo].[LinkTbl]
```

functions just as quickly.

However,

```
INSERT INTO [LocalDB].[dbo].[LocalTbl] (Id, Val) 
SELECT TOP(2) Id, Val 
FROM [LinkSrvr].[LinkDB].[dbo].[LinkTbl]
```

(and any `TOP(n)` greater) simply sits and says "executing query" for a seemingly indefinite amount of time, and never inserts any records.

I have only just started working with Linked Servers, so I am not sure if that may be playing a part in this.

Comment: Try adding (nolock) at the end of query to see if that works

Comment: So you're saying `TOP 2` and `TOP 3` give different performance? How do the query plans compare? (CTRL-L). Just analyse the `select` part for now -  exclude the insert part while trying to troubleshoot. Note that without an `ORDER BY`, you can't guarantee which 10 records you'll get.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Top(1) returns results immediately, any other value just seems to run the query indefinitely without returning anything.

Comment: @Harsh Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try when I have a chance. I should also mention, nothing *should* have been modifying [LinkTbl] for at least three months now, but I could be wrong!

Comment: As a side note, I shudder every time I see a TOP without an ORDER BY. You cannot guarantee an expected order or consistent results without explicitly ordering your result set.

Comment: @Eric Is `[LinkTbl]` a table or view?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Normally I would agree, but in this particular case we were simply trying to grab a sample of items from [linkTbl], so _which_ records are returned is not as important as how many are returned. Still, a very valid point that a lot of people seem to overlook.

Comment: @lad2025 It is a table.

Comment: @Eric Please provide it's full structure tables you insert to and select from

Comment: @lad2025 Unfortunately, I cannot provide the actual data structures due to the proprietary nature of the data, but I will see if I can at least provide a more representative structure with column names different than the actual ones.

Comment: @Eric skip names, just overall structure, types, constraint and indexes. Check especially for XML/ntext/image columns

Comment: @Eric Even better please post image of execution plans both TOP 1 and TOP n, of course cover sensitive data

Comment: Turns out the issue was related to two varchar(MAX) columns in the source table. Many of the records have a very large restore script stored in those columns, which was slowing everything down. I eventually ended up just using a while loop to iterate through each record and complete the tasks we needed.